# How can make the Grid or ViewBox fill the ItemsControl?(WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, xaml, desktop-application

I got problems in ViewBox or Border in ItemControl.

I want to make a card showing some content. On the left side of the card is the picture. In order to make the picture look better (rounded border), I set this picture as a Border background. Such code is as follows:

```
<Border
    x:Name="cardBorder"
    Grid.Row="0" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="{Binding Image, IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource ImageBrushConverter}}"
    CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
    Opacity="0.7" />
```

The background image of the Border needs to be bound to an Image property of my DailyPage class. So I modified the code to look like this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DailyPages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>

                <Border
                    x:Name="cardBorder"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="{Binding Image, IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource ImageBrushConverter}}"
                    CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                    Opacity="0.7" />

            </Viewbox>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However, the result of doing this is nothing is displayed.As shown below：
[The Image can't be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf4PY.png)
But if I modified the border's code as below

```
<Border
    x:Name="cardBorder"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="{Binding Image, IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource ImageBrushConverter}}"
    CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
    Opacity="0.7" 
/>
```

The Image appears!

[An Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2R3t.png)

I checked the ViewsTree and find that the ItemsControl's panel is as big as this:

[Filling the whole space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSp1d.png)

However, the ViewBox and the Border are only as small as shown below:

[Only a small part of the ItemsControl's space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4zWx.png)

It's too ugly.How can I fix it?

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd Borders look identical.

Comment: I modified the 2nd to be the 3rd and the Border appeared. But this can't make the border fill the whole panel automatically.